# why does libvlcsharp winform mosaic with 16 channels use a lot of CPU

Tags: winforms, libvlcsharp

Setup as follows: A winform app, visual studio 2019, create 16 videoview/mediaplayer instances, each streaming a 960 X 540 30fps camera stream from a multicasting camera.

CPU i7 2.67GHz, GPU NV GTX 1650.

The GPU is loading up to 44% decode and about the same for 3d. The application uses an amazing 75 to 90% of the CPU. It jumps around a lot from one test run to another. The GPU is very stable.

Here's some other information that is interesting. If I run a single copy of this application with one video stream the CPU use is about 5/10% of CPU. If I run 16 instances of the application each instance uses about 4/10 to 8/10% of the CPU. Once I have 16 videos streaming the GPU is same as above (44%) the CPU is nominal.

The increase of CPU usage within one instance while adding cameras is not linear it takes a big jump after 9.
From the diagnostic image below you can see the usage is isolated almost entirely in the Native code. Other diagrams show about 2/3 in the kernel and 1/3 in system IO. The CPU is spread across all the cores pretty evenly.

[image]

[code on gist](https://gist.github.com/mooncaptain-io/6d400af465fd1e94f7dc7a0b2be97ad8)

I have tried a lot of variations on this but no matter what I try the CPU usage is pretty constant once I get up to 16 channels. I have tried running each instance within its own thread. That made no difference. I really would like to understand this and find a way to reduce CPU usage. I have an application that uses this tech and a customer that requires even more channels than 16.

Comment: Hard to say without the full code. Please post a minimal sample on GitHub. Do you listen to any event on your video views? What CommandLine do you pass? What kind of media do you play?

Comment: @cube45 CommandLine is --verbose=2. Only event is ApplicationExit. Media is Multicast IP camera stream. – mooncaptain 1 hour ago

Comment: @cube45 embedded link to code above

Comment: @cube45 so i cut down the code to the bare minimum that will produce the CPU usage. That is what I posted to Gist. All it takes is a 16 iteration loop and create a new mediaplayer each time. videoview isn't required. Also you can substitute a an mp4 or other video file and the same problem will happen. Also resolution doesn't matter too much just the number to streams.

Comment: Did you try on another computer, with another GPU brand ? I suspect a libvlc limitation somehow. If you don't manage to find an answer, I'd suggest that you open a ticket on vlc's bug tracker.

Comment: @cube45 I have run this on a least 3 other computers. Those systems were running RTX 2080 ti graphics engines and had dual processors with  64 logical cores. It takes 25 streams to get up to 80% CPU usage. We have only ever used Nvidia cards.

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/262

Comment: Need a C/C++ repro for VLC devs

Comment: also please enable verbose libvlc logs and share them in full here

Comment: @mfkl just updated the gist entry with the --verbose=2 log. Use link in op

Comment: @mfkl - I don't have the skill set for c or c++ to reproduce in that world. Not enough spare time at the moment to get up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug, which would need to be reported on trac.videolan.org with a minimal C/C++ reproduction sample for the VLC developers.

Do note that comparing 16 VLC app instances (16 processes) playing and 1 LibVLC-based app instance playing 16 streams (1 process) is not exactly a fair comparison.

The perf usage should still be linear and not exponential, though, so maybe there is a bug.

Comment: I appreciate the attention this question received. Thank you. I will, at some time in the future, when I have time, sharpen up my C skills and create a test harness to demonstrate (or not) this problem. For now I will just let the question remain unanswered. Also thanks for Note regarding the comparison.